# A column of conditional lagged values in R with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
df
     seller_id buyer_id       hs10 year mean_ln_c_hit
  1:         1        5 1200000000    5      4.407456
  2:         1       24 1500000000    2      4.173422
  3:         1        8 1500000000    3      4.532695
  4:         1        8 1500000000    5      4.830106
  5:         1       16 1500000000    5      4.830106
  6:         1       17 1800000000    3      3.920435
  7:         1       20 1800000000    5      4.357196
  8:         1       27 1800000000    5      4.357196
  9:         1        1 1900000000    1      4.835762
 10:         1        2 1900000000    1      4.835762
 11:         1        3 1900000000    1      4.835762
 12:         1        4 1900000000    1      4.835762
 13:         1        5 1900000000    1      4.835762
 14:         1        6 1900000000    1      4.835762
 15:         1        7 1900000000    1      4.835762
 16:         1        8 1900000000    1      4.835762
 17:         1        9 1900000000    1      4.835762
 18:         1       11 1900000000    1      4.835762
 19:         1       12 1900000000    1      4.835762
 20:         1       13 1900000000    1      4.835762
 21:         1       14 1900000000    1      4.835762
 22:         1       15 1900000000    1      4.835762
 23:         1       16 1900000000    1      4.835762
 24:         1       17 1900000000    1      4.835762
 25:         1       18 1900000000    1      4.835762
 26:         1       19 1900000000    1      4.835762
 27:         1       20 1900000000    1      4.835762
 28:         1       21 1900000000    1      4.835762
 29:         1       22 1900000000    1      4.835762
 30:         1       23 1900000000    1      4.835762
 31:         1       24 1900000000    1      4.835762
 32:         1       25 1900000000    1      4.835762
 33:         1       26 1900000000    1      4.835762
 34:         1       27 1900000000    1      4.835762
 35:         1       28 1900000000    1      4.835762
 36:         1       29 1900000000    1      4.835762
 37:         1       30 1900000000    1      4.835762
 38:         1        1 1900000000    2      4.409253
 39:         1        2 1900000000    2      4.409253
 40:         1        3 1900000000    2      4.409253
 41:         1        4 1900000000    2      4.409253
 42:         1        5 1900000000    2      4.409253
 43:         1        6 1900000000    2      4.409253
 44:         1        7 1900000000    2      4.409253
 45:         1        8 1900000000    2      4.409253
 46:         1        9 1900000000    2      4.409253
 47:         1       10 1900000000    2      4.409253
 48:         1       11 1900000000    2      4.409253
 49:         1       12 1900000000    2      4.409253
 50:         1       13 1900000000    2      4.409253
 51:         1       14 1900000000    2      4.409253
 52:         1       15 1900000000    2      4.409253
 53:         1       16 1900000000    2      4.409253
 54:         1       17 1900000000    2      4.409253
 55:         1       18 1900000000    2      4.409253
 56:         1       19 1900000000    2      4.409253
 57:         1       20 1900000000    2      4.409253
 58:         1       21 1900000000    2      4.409253
 59:         1       22 1900000000    2      4.409253
 60:         1       23 1900000000    2      4.409253
 61:         1       25 1900000000    2      4.409253
 62:         1       26 1900000000    2      4.409253
 63:         1       27 1900000000    2      4.409253
 64:         1       28 1900000000    2      4.409253
 65:         1       29 1900000000    2      4.409253
 66:         1       30 1900000000    2      4.409253
 67:         1        1 1900000000    3      4.514642
 68:         1        3 1900000000    3      4.514642
 69:         1        4 1900000000    3      4.514642
 70:         1        5 1900000000    3      4.514642
 71:         1        6 1900000000    3      4.514642
 72:         1        7 1900000000    3      4.514642
 73:         1        9 1900000000    3      4.514642
 74:         1       11 1900000000    3      4.514642
 75:         1       12 1900000000    3      4.514642
 76:         1       13 1900000000    3      4.514642
 77:         1       14 1900000000    3      4.514642
 78:         1       15 1900000000    3      4.514642
 79:         1       16 1900000000    3      4.514642
 80:         1       18 1900000000    3      4.514642
 81:         1       19 1900000000    3      4.514642
 82:         1       20 1900000000    3      4.514642
 83:         1       21 1900000000    3      4.514642
 84:         1       22 1900000000    3      4.514642
 85:         1       23 1900000000    3      4.514642
 86:         1       24 1900000000    3      4.514642
 87:         1       25 1900000000    3      4.514642
 88:         1       26 1900000000    3      4.514642
 89:         1       27 1900000000    3      4.514642
 90:         1       28 1900000000    3      4.514642
 91:         1       29 1900000000    3      4.514642
 92:         1       30 1900000000    3      4.514642
 93:         1        2 1900000000    5      4.698335
 94:         1        3 1900000000    5      4.698335
 95:         1        4 1900000000    5      4.698335
 96:         1        6 1900000000    5      4.698335
 97:         1        7 1900000000    5      4.698335
 98:         1        9 1900000000    5      4.698335
 99:         1       11 1900000000    5      4.698335
100:         1       12 1900000000    5      4.698335
```

I want to use `data.table` feature to create a new column called `lag_mean_ln_c_hit` which contains the one-year lag `lag` of the value in column `mean_ln_c_hit`, conditional on the `seller_id` and `hs10`. My best attempt is:

```
df[!is.na(year), lag_mean_ln_c_hit:= 
                        (.SD[.(seller_id = seller_id, hs10 = hs10, year = year - 1), mean_ln_c_hit, on = c("seller_id", "hs10", "year"), allow.cartesian = TRUE ]) ]
```

which kind of correctly pics when to display `NAs` (i.e., `year = 1` is the first year, so the lag for all observations in the first `year` should be NA), but fails to capture the right lags. It always report `4.835762` for any other combination that is not `NA` (albeit once it reports `4.173422`).

Each `seller_id` has multiple `buyer_id` entries with the same `mean_ln_c_hit` value. Therefore I have duplicates. Running the code, I get the following `Warning as well`

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(df, !is.na(year), `:=`(lag_mean_ln_c_hit, (.SD[.(seller_id = seller_id,  :
  Supplied 1640 items to be assigned to 100 items of column 'lag_mean_ln_c_hit' (1540 unused)
```

The code would not run without `allow.cartesian = TRUE`.

Any idea on how to solve this issue? It should be pretty simple, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: what if there are no data in the 1 year lag? what is your desired output for this sample data?

Comment: If there're no date in the 1 year lag I would like to have `NA`s. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clear what is the desired output. If it has to be exactly one year ago, here is an option:

```
seller <- unique(df, by=c("seller_id", "hs10", "year"))
df[, oneyearago := year - 1L]
df[, lag_mean_ln_c_hit := seller[.SD, on=.(seller_id, hs10, year=oneyearago), x.mean_ln_c_hit]]
```

output:

```
     seller_id buyer_id       hs10 year mean_ln_c_hit oneyearago lag_mean_ln_c_hit
  1:         1        5 1200000000    5      4.407456          4                NA
  2:         1       24 1500000000    2      4.173422          1                NA
  3:         1        8 1500000000    3      4.532695          2          4.173422
  4:         1        8 1500000000    5      4.830106          4                NA
  5:         1       16 1500000000    5      4.830106          4                NA
  6:         1       17 1800000000    3      3.920435          2                NA
  7:         1       20 1800000000    5      4.357196          4                NA
  8:         1       27 1800000000    5      4.357196          4                NA
  9:         1        1 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 10:         1        2 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 11:         1        3 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 12:         1        4 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 13:         1        5 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 14:         1        6 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 15:         1        7 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 16:         1        8 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 17:         1        9 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 18:         1       11 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 19:         1       12 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 20:         1       13 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 21:         1       14 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 22:         1       15 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 23:         1       16 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 24:         1       17 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 25:         1       18 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 26:         1       19 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 27:         1       20 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 28:         1       21 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 29:         1       22 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 30:         1       23 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 31:         1       24 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 32:         1       25 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 33:         1       26 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 34:         1       27 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 35:         1       28 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 36:         1       29 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 37:         1       30 1900000000    1      4.835762          0                NA
 38:         1        1 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 39:         1        2 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 40:         1        3 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 41:         1        4 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 42:         1        5 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 43:         1        6 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 44:         1        7 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 45:         1        8 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 46:         1        9 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 47:         1       10 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 48:         1       11 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 49:         1       12 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 50:         1       13 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 51:         1       14 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 52:         1       15 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 53:         1       16 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 54:         1       17 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 55:         1       18 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 56:         1       19 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 57:         1       20 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 58:         1       21 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 59:         1       22 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 60:         1       23 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 61:         1       25 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 62:         1       26 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 63:         1       27 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 64:         1       28 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 65:         1       29 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 66:         1       30 1900000000    2      4.409253          1          4.835762
 67:         1        1 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 68:         1        3 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 69:         1        4 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 70:         1        5 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 71:         1        6 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 72:         1        7 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 73:         1        9 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 74:         1       11 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 75:         1       12 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 76:         1       13 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 77:         1       14 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 78:         1       15 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 79:         1       16 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 80:         1       18 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 81:         1       19 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 82:         1       20 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 83:         1       21 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 84:         1       22 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 85:         1       23 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 86:         1       24 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 87:         1       25 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 88:         1       26 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 89:         1       27 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 90:         1       28 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 91:         1       29 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 92:         1       30 1900000000    3      4.514642          2          4.409253
 93:         1        2 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
 94:         1        3 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
 95:         1        4 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
 96:         1        6 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
 97:         1        7 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
 98:         1        9 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
 99:         1       11 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
100:         1       12 1900000000    5      4.698335          4                NA
     seller_id buyer_id       hs10 year mean_ln_c_hit oneyearago lag_mean_ln_c_hit
```

Or if it has be at least one year ago, you can use a non-equi join and pick the last match:

```
seller <- unique(df, by=c("seller_id", "hs10", "year"))
df[, lag_mean_ln_c_hit := seller[.SD, on=.(seller_id, hs10, year<year), x.mean_ln_c_hit, mult="last"]]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("seller_id buyer_id       hs10 year mean_ln_c_hit
1        5 1200000000    5      4.407456
1       24 1500000000    2      4.173422
1        8 1500000000    3      4.532695
1        8 1500000000    5      4.830106
1       16 1500000000    5      4.830106
1       17 1800000000    3      3.920435
1       20 1800000000    5      4.357196
1       27 1800000000    5      4.357196
1        1 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        2 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        3 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        4 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        5 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        6 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        7 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        8 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        9 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       11 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       12 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       13 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       14 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       15 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       16 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       17 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       18 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       19 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       20 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       21 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       22 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       23 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       24 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       25 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       26 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       27 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       28 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       29 1900000000    1      4.835762
1       30 1900000000    1      4.835762
1        1 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        2 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        3 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        4 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        5 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        6 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        7 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        8 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        9 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       10 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       11 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       12 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       13 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       14 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       15 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       16 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       17 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       18 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       19 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       20 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       21 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       22 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       23 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       25 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       26 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       27 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       28 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       29 1900000000    2      4.409253
1       30 1900000000    2      4.409253
1        1 1900000000    3      4.514642
1        3 1900000000    3      4.514642
1        4 1900000000    3      4.514642
1        5 1900000000    3      4.514642
1        6 1900000000    3      4.514642
1        7 1900000000    3      4.514642
1        9 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       11 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       12 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       13 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       14 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       15 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       16 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       18 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       19 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       20 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       21 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       22 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       23 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       24 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       25 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       26 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       27 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       28 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       29 1900000000    3      4.514642
1       30 1900000000    3      4.514642
1        2 1900000000    5      4.698335
1        3 1900000000    5      4.698335
1        4 1900000000    5      4.698335
1        6 1900000000    5      4.698335
1        7 1900000000    5      4.698335
1        9 1900000000    5      4.698335
1       11 1900000000    5      4.698335
1       12 1900000000    5      4.698335")
```

Comment: It seems to me that the main difference between the code I came up with and your solution is the `x.mean_ln_c_hit`. What does that do?

Comment: it refers to the column `mean_ln_c_hit` in `x` of a `x[i]` join/